# CodeModel Modifier Order

Tags: java, sonarqube, modifier

Using CodeModel, is there a way to control the order of modifiers?
Specifically when creating fields.

CodeModel seems to have it's own definition of modifier order which differs than that of the Java Language Specification and products like SonarQube and CheckStyle:

https://sonar43.spring.io/rules/show/squid:ModifiersOrderCheck?layout=false
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html

Modifiers should appear in the following order:

1. Annotations
2. public
3. protected
4. private
5. abstract
6. static
7. final
8. transient
9. volatile
10. synchronized
11. native
12. strictfp

This sample code:

```
// Create field for serialVersionUID
JFieldVar field1 = newClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE | JMod.STATIC | JMod.FINAL, long.class, "serialVersionUID");
field1.init(JExpr.lit(1L));
```

Produces the following modifiers that does not follow suggested order:

```
private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible*. Not even nasty reflection hacks will do it. The order of the modifiers is determined by the [`JMods#generate(JFormatter)`](https://java.net/projects/codemodel/sources/svn/content/trunk/codemodel/codemodel/src/main/java/com/sun/codemodel/JMods.java?rev=333) method (at the bottom). Unfortunately, the `JMods` class has only a single constructor that is explicitly declared as `private`.

---

*<sub>Of course, you can add another layer of instrumentation, bytecode assembly or similar, or just create a modified version of CodeModel for local use. But there is no non-intrusive way of changing the modifier order.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you for the advise. I'll make the change locally for my purposes. Any idea if the group is accepting change requests? If so, how do I get this one into the queue?

Comment: Not sure about the change requests. The last change in the source was 2 years ago. And java.net is going to be shut down sooner or later. There are some clones/forks on GitHub, but I don't know an "official" repo, unfortunately...